# Google Bigquery first call too slow for the first call when used with python

Tags: python, api, google-bigquery

Apparently, the first call made using python to google bigquery is taking twice longer as other attempts. Looks like the system goes on sleep, is there any way to avoid this first time delay?

Comment: BQ doesn't have any sleep. The first call be a longer https handshake.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain what exactly you are expecting over BQ, if you are trying to upload data to BQ using Python then you can use following code

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io import gbq
import os
import numpy as np
dept_dt=pd.read_csv('dept_data')
#print(dept_dt)

# Replace with Project Id
project = 'xxxxxxx'

#Replace with service account path
path_service_account = 'yyyyyyyyyyy.json'

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = path_service_account


dept_dt.to_gbq(destination_table='test1.Emp_data1',project_id='xxxxxxxxxx',if_exists='fail')
```

If your requirement is to read from BQ table then you can use [Apache beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65436564/apache-beam-io-bigquerysource-use-standard-sql-not-working-when-running-as-dataf/65437789#65437789) to pull data from BQ.