# Creating table in big query by uploading csv

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to big query . I am trying o create a table by uploading csv. Its size if 290 kb. Even if I fill all the required information the thee dots beside create table keeps moving(like loading ) but even after waiting for a long time, the table doesn't get created.

Comment: Can you please post the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the CSV in a bucket and then reference it from BigQuery creation panel.
Here is the official guide from Google, with the screenshot. Should be rather simple. ( https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect)

On step 4 of the image below, select the path to the file and CSV format.

On step 5 you can either keep everything like it is or select "External Table" (which I recommend), in order to delete the table in case of error and not lose the CSV.

BigQuery should automatically handle the rest. Please, share more detailed information in case of error.

[image: Doc with BigQuery creation panel]

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways through which you can upload CSV file to Bigquery as given below :-

1. Write an Apache beam code (Python/Java) and get data loaded to Bigquery. Sample code for [reading](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py) and [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65436564/apache-beam-io-bigquerysource-use-standard-sql-not-working-when-running-as-dataf/65437789#65437789) you can combine it.
2. Write a python script which is responsible for loading data to Bigquery.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io import gbq
import os
import numpy as np
dept_dt=pd.read_csv('dept_data')
#print(dept_dt)

# Replace with Project Id
project = 'xxxxx-aaaaa-de'

#Replace with service account path
path_service_account = 'xxxxx-aaaa-jhhhhh9874.json'

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = path_service_account


dept_dt.to_gbq(destination_table='test1.Emp_data1',project_id='xxxxxx-ccvd-err',if_exists='fail')
```