# Apache Beam To BigQuery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am building a process in Google Cloud Dataflow that will consume messages in a Pub/Sub and based on a value of one key it will either write them to BQ or to GCS. I am able to split the messages, but I am not sure how to write the data to BigQuery. I've tried using the `beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery`, but no luck.

My full code is here: https://pastebin.com/4W9Vu4Km

Basically my issue is that I don't know, how to specify in the `WriteBatchesToBQ` (line 73) that the variable `element` should be written into BQ.

I've also tried using `beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery` directly in the pipeline (line 128), but then I got an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' [while running 'Write to BQ/_StreamToBigQuery/StreamInsertRows/ParDo(BigQueryWriteFn)']` . This is probably because I am not feeding it a dictionary, but a list of dictionaries (I would like to use 1-minute windows).

Any ideas please? (also if there is something too stupid in the code, let me know - I am playing with apache beam just for a short time and I might be overlooking some obvious issues).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second approach is the solution to this issue, you need to use WriteToBigQuery function directly in the pipeline. However, a beam.FlatMap step needs to be included so the WriteToBigQuery can process the list of dictionaries correctly.

Hence the complete pipeline splitting data, grouping them by time, and writing them into BQ is defined like this:

```
 accepted_messages = tagged_lines_result[Split.OUTPUT_TAG_BQ] | "Window into BQ" >> GroupWindowsIntoBatches(
            window_size) | "FlatMap" >> beam.FlatMap(
            lambda elements: elements) | "Write to BQ" >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(table=output_table_bq,
                                                                                               schema=(
                                                                                                   output_table_bq_schema),
                                                                                               write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                                                               create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
```

The complete working code is here: https://pastebin.com/WFwBvPcU

Answer (score 2):

WriteToBigQuery sample format is given below:-

```
    project_id = "proj1"
    dataset_id = 'dataset1'
    table_id = 'table1'
    table_schema = ('id:STRING, reqid:STRING')

        | 'Write-CH' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                                    table=table_id,
                                                    dataset=dataset_id,
                                                    project=project_id,
                                                    schema=table_schema,
                                                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
                                                    ))
```

You can refer this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65436564/apache-beam-io-bigquerysource-use-standard-sql-not-working-when-running-as-dataf/65437789#65437789) it will give you a brief understanding of beam data pipeline.

Comment: Hi Vibhor, this unfortunately didn't help. I've updated the line 127 (like this https://pastebin.com/8HUuCbLu), but I am getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items' [while running 'Write to BQ/_StreamToBigQuery/StreamInsertRows/ParDo(BigQueryWriteFn)']
` as mentioned in the question (probably because GroupWindowsIntoBatches produces a list of dictionaries instead of a dictionary).

Comment: From where you have got list ```tagged_lines_result[Split.OUTPUT_TAG_BQ]```, Generally before approaching to beam.io.WriteToBigQuery, data should have been parsed in pipeline. Try to refer sample code which i have shared in my post. Split records in ParDo or in pipeline and then go for writing data.

Comment: I got it on line 118 here https://pastebin.com/4W9Vu4Km. The reason I am using it is because I need to split the pipeline into two streams (one to BQ, other one to GCS). I am getting the list, because I am using the window function. Is it possible to somehow feed a list of dictionaries to the WriteToBigQuery?

Comment: Yes, Its possible to load a list to BigQuery, but it depends how you wanted to load. If you wanted to load complete data as a list then map list over an element and load data to a single STRING field. If you want to split each element of list individually in each coll then split it using ParDo or in Pipeline and map each element to individual fields of a BigQuery.

Comment: I have a list of dictionaries, all the dictionaries have keys that correspond to column names in the destination table. One dictionary represents one row in the destination table. Could you give me any tips on what functions it would be best to use given what I have so far?

Comment: OK, using FlatMap(lambda elements: elements) worked and the flow is now correctly splitting messages into two locations (GCS and BQ). Thanks @Vibhor for your time, I will be posting a detailed answer once I wrap my head around this a bit more.

Comment: Great, All the best.