# Windowed Pub/Sub messages to BigQuery in Apache Beam

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm working on a proof-of-concept solution that will read messages from Pub/Sub and write them to a table in BigQuery. The final solution-to-be is going to be more complex so before starting working on this one I'd like to wrap my head around something simpler.

The code in the example pipeline is supposed to read messages from an (unbounded) Pub/Sub source, do few transformations and save rows in a BigQuery table. Based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66334936/apache-beam-to-bigquery) I created the following Apache Beam pipeline:

```
import argparse
import json
import logging
import os
from abc import ABC
import datetime

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.transforms.window import TimestampedValue
from apache_beam.transforms.window import FixedWindows

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = './credentials/dataflow_service_account.json'
SUBSCRIPTION = "projects/project-data-engineering-ci/subscriptions/beam-local-sub"


class GroupWindowsIntoBatches(beam.PTransform):
    """
    A composite transform that groups Pub/Sub messages based on publish
    time and outputs a list of dictionaries, where each contains one message
    and its publish timestamp.
    """

    def __init__(self, window_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.window_size = window_size

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (
                pcoll
                # Assigns window info to each Pub/Sub message based on its
                # cluster time.
                | "Window into Fixed Intervals" >> beam.WindowInto(FixedWindows(self.window_size))
                | "Add timestamps to messages" >> beam.ParDo(AddTimestamps())
                | "Add Dummy Key" >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (None, elem))
                | "Groupby" >> beam.GroupByKey()
                | "Abandon Dummy Key" >> beam.MapTuple(lambda _, val: val)
        )


class AddTimestamps(beam.DoFn, ABC):
    def process(self, element, **kwargs):
        unix_timestamp = int(element['meta']['cluster_time'].split("-")[0])
        element = (element['meta']['cluster_time'], element['payload'])
        yield TimestampedValue(element, unix_timestamp)


class PrintValue(beam.DoFn, ABC):
    def process(self, element, **kwargs):
        print(element)
        return [element]


class PrepareRow(beam.DoFn, ABC):
    def process(self, element, **kwargs):
        migration_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
        migration_id = "windowed migration_id"

        return [
            {"raw_contents": element['payload'], "migration_datetime": migration_datetime, "migration_id": migration_id}
        ]


TABLE_SCHEMA = {
    "fields": [
        {"name": "raw_contents", 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {"name": "migration_datetime", 'type': 'DATETIME', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {"name": "migration_id", 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}
    ]
}


def run(input_subscription,
        output_table_bq,
        output_table_bq_schema,
        window_size,
        pipeline_args=None):
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
        pipeline_args, streaming=True, save_main_session=True, direct_running_mode='in_memory', direct_num_workers=2
    )

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        events = (pipeline
                  | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription)
                  | "Convert bytes to a dictionary" >> beam.Map(lambda e: json.loads(e.decode('utf-8'))))
        _ = (events
             | "Group Windows Into Batches" >> GroupWindowsIntoBatches(window_size)
             | "FlatMap" >> beam.FlatMap(lambda elements: elements)
             | "Prepare rows before inserting" >> beam.ParDo(PrepareRow())
             | "Write to BQ" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table=output_table_bq,
                                                        schema=output_table_bq_schema,
                                                        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED
                                                        ))
    pipeline.run().wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--input_subscription",
        dest='input_subscription',
        help="The Cloud Pub/Sub subscription to read from.\n"
             '"projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION_NAME>".',
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--window_size",
        dest='window_size',
        type=int,
        default=10,
        help="Output file's window size in number of seconds.",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--output_table_bq",
        dest='output_table_bq',
        required=True,
        help="BQ Table for output. Format: <project_id:dataset.table>",
    )
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    run(
        input_subscription=known_args.input_subscription,
        output_table_bq=known_args.output_table_bq,
        window_size=known_args.window_size,
        output_table_bq_schema=TABLE_SCHEMA,
        pipeline_args=pipeline_args,
    )
```

The problem with the pipeline in its current shape and form is that it doesn't load rows into BigQuery. If I comment out stages `"Group Windows Into Batches"` and `"FlatMap"`, rows are loaded correctly into BigQuery. The grouping-windows-into-batches functionality is critical in the final solution (unifying Cloud Storage JSON files and Pub/Sub messages) so I need it to work. How should I change my pipeline?

EDIT:
The messages coming from Pub/Sub (having been transformed from bytes to a dictionary) look like this:

```
 {
     "meta": {
         "source": {
             "coll": "coll_name",
             "db": "db_name"
         },
         "cluster_time": "1234-1",
         "payload_type": "object",
         "op_type": "insert"
     },
     "payload": "some string"
  }
```

Comment: Due to not having access to “abc” used here “from abc import ABC”, I could not reproduce. Could you please help me with the package for reproduction on my end?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6 and the `abc` module is available out of the box: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/abc.html