# BigQuery events calculation

Tags: google-bigquery, analytics, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have table with events with start datetime, and event_name. event_name can belong to a start or an end events.
I need to calculate sum of differences between datetime of start and end events pairs with following rule: stop event datetime minus earliest start event datime before that stop event datime, e.g.:

Start 1, Start 2, Stop 1, Start 3, Stop 2

sum((Stop1 - Start1),(Stop2-Start3)).

Do you have some ideas how to do it using sql with analitical functions? From my perspective loop would be necessery so either stored procedure (which is not possible) or apache beam with dataflow for calculating data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following Bigquery SQL to find difference between 2 `DATETIME` fields.
Referral [Doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_diff).

```
SELECT DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME '2018-02-20', DATETIME '2018-01-15', DAY) as days_diff;
```

Then You can Write an Apache Beam code to Read data from BQ using BQ-SQL you have created above then after apply all transformation logic you can write to Target (BQ table or GCS or BT). Here you will get sample [Beam code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65436564/apache-beam-io-bigquerysource-use-standard-sql-not-working-when-running-as-dataf/65437789#65437789).